# How to sum credit hours in a nested list

Tags: python, arrays, nested-lists

I have a nested array. I need to get the sum of credit hours. The credit hours are in position [2] and [5] respectively. How do I achieve this using a for loop in python? I'm not conversant in Numpy.

```
marks = [   
    [ "MR. JONES", "ACCT203", 2, 3.0, "CIS100", 3, 2.5 ],
    [ "SKARE EEEY", "ACCT203", 2, 2.5, "BUS123", 2, 3.0 ],
    [ "HALO WEEN", "ACCT300", 5, 2.0, "ACCT301", 2, 1.5 ],
    [ "BOB KATZ", "ACCT300", 5, 1.0, "BUS278", 3, 4.0 ],
    [ "ANNIE BANANE", "ACCT300", 5, 0.0, "CIS223", 3, 1.5 ],
]
```

All I have managed to do is print them. I'm stuck beyond this.

```
for credit_hours in marks:
    cred_hours_part_one = credit_hours[2]
    cred_hours_part_two = credit_hours[5]
    print(cred_hours_part_one)
    print(cred_hours_part_two)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this if you want the total sum:

```py
total = sum([mark[2] + mark[5] for mark in marks])
print(total)
32
```

Or if you want the sum of every element in a nice dict:

```py
results = {mark[0]: mark[2] + mark[5] for mark in marks}
print(results)
{'MR. JONES': 5, 'SKARE EEEY': 4, 'HALO WEEN': 7, 'BOB KATZ': 8, 'ANNIE BANANE': 8}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The credit hours are in position [2] and [5] respectively.

So I assume you only want to sum the `int`egers at indexes `2` and `5`.

```
[ "MR. JONES", "ACCT203", 2, 3.0, "CIS100", 3, 2.5 ]
```

---

To get a single `list` from a nested `list`, you just have to take it from its index, for example:

```
>>> marks[0] # ...will give you...
[ "MR. JONES", "ACCT203", 2, 3.0, "CIS100", 3, 2.5 ]
```

So now you just have to sum its `2`nd and `5`th positions, for example:

```
>>> marks[0][2] + marks[0][5]
5
```

If you want to gather all the sums, you just have to use a `list` comprehension...

```
list_of_the_sums_of_the_marks = [mark[2] + mark[5] for mark in marks]
```

...and then to sum it...

```
sum(list_of_the_sums_of_the_marks)
```

---

I would suggest you to read something about [`nested lists`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-list-comprehensions-in-python/).

Comment: i want sum ALL the integers in those positions and get a total like 200 credit hours. Not in a single array. So i need a for loop that will add per array then add them after addition per array. I hope you get me now.

Comment: Ok, I'm editing my answer: